ASP .Net Core. Вырезается эндпоинт "endpoint-test-test" при использовании HttpClient.PostAsync();
Полная ссылка http://server.ru/endpoint-test-test/method, проблема заключается в том, что при использовании в url два дефиса эндпоинт вырезается и ссылка приобретает вид http://server.ru/method из за чего возвращается ответ 404.

Возможно где то в вашем коде есть кастомный обработчик который выполняе такие действия
